# Python package import slow relative to standard packages

Tags: python, package

I am writing a Python Package, but using %timeit it is ~4 x as slow as importing other packages such as pandas. My package is basic and I have pushed an sdist to PyPI test. Why is this the case?

1.91 Microseconds vs. 490 Nano Seconds for Pandas

I have noticed that this happens only on the first import, in the ipython session, which is slow. Does python have to re-compile the .pyc files (nothing in the source files have changed) on each first import? Subsequent imports are as fast as other packages (I assume due to being in memory). Do I need to use bdist to pre-build packages for each platform to improve import speed?

Comment: Python caches the module in `sys.modules`, so subsequent imports are fast (the module is already imported).  Generally speaking, since the import only needs to do real work on the first go, your users will never notice the import time anyway so it's probably not worth losing any sleep over.

Comment: pandas has a great deal of native code, so perhaps that's why?